# D3: + operator before object call

Tags: javascript, d3.js

It's not clear to me what the + operator is doing in this specific context, or what it does in the below context generally in javascript. Inside of the projection function.

```
 function agg_year(leaves) {
            var total = d3.sum(leaves, function(d) {
                return d['attendance'];
            });

            var coords = leaves.map(function(d) {
                return projection([+d.long, +d.lat]);
            });

            var center_x = d3.mean(coords, function(d) {
                return d[0];
            });

            var center_y = d3.mean(coords, function(d) {
                return d[1];
            });

            return {
              'attendance' : total,
              'x' : center_x,
              'y' : center_y
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It coerces a value to a number in javascript. So, in case you have two string values inside an array:

```
var latitude = '10'; //this is a string
var longitude = '20'; //this is a string
```

This would create a string array, right?

```
var coordinates = [latitude, longitude]; // -> two strings, ['10', '20'];
```

Now this creates an array of numbers (the `+` is used to coerce a value to a number):

```
var coordinates = [+latitude, +longitude]; // -> two numbers,  [10, 20];
```

More examples below:

```
var a = null;
typeof a; //object.
typeof +a; //number
+a; //0

var b = '5';
typeof b; //string
typeof +b; //number
+b; //5
```

Comment: perfect! Thanks for the thorough explanation